# What is the most efficient way to print a file in C to stdout?

Tags: c, file

I'm stuck on this. Currently I'm using:

```
FILE *a = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
int n;
while ((n = fgetc(a)) != EOF) {
  putchar(n);
}
```

However this method seems to be a bit inefficient. Is there any better way? I tried using fgets:

```
char *s;
fgets(s, 600, a);
puts(s);
```

There's one thing I find wrong about this second method, which is that you would need a really large number for the second argument of fgets.

Thanks for all the suggestions. I found a way (someone on IRC told me this) using open(), read(), and write().

```
char *filename = "sample.txt";
char buf[8192];
int r = -1;
int in = open(filename, O_RDONLY), out = 0;
if (in == -1)
  return -1;
while (1) {
  r = read(in, buf, sizeof(buf));
  if (r == -1 || r == 0) { break; }
  r = write(out, buf, r);
  if (r == -1 || r == 0) { break; }
}
```

Comment: define what you mean by inefficient.

Comment: In efficient, I mean something that doesn't take a lot of memory but also doesn't print by every char.

Comment: `puts()` does a bit more than you think it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second code is broken. You need to allocate a buffer, e.g.:

```
char s[4096];
fgets(s, sizeof(s), a);
```

Of course, this doesn't solve your problem.

Read fix-size chunks from the input and write out whatever gets read in:

```
int n;
char s[65536];
while ((n = fread(s, 1, sizeof(s), a))) {
    fwrite(s, 1, n, stdout);
}
```

You might also want to check `ferror(a)` in case it stopped for some other reason than reaching EOF.

### Notes

1. I originally used a 4096 byte buffer because it is a fairly common page size for memory allocation and block size for the file system. However, the sweet-spot on my Linux system seems to be around the 64 kB mark, which surprised me. Perhaps CPU cache is a factor here, but I'm just guessing.
2. For a cold cache, it makes almost no difference, since I/O paging will dominate; even one byte at a time runs at about the same speed.

Comment: Tiny mistake in there: it should read `fwrite(s, 1, n, stdout)`

Comment: @Joey: I spotted it while debugging, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Actually, this is a very good answer. Multiples of the page size and disk block size are very good for performance. You may want to test other multiples, I've had very good results with 65536 for disk to disk copies.

Comment: If you're copying large chunks, there's no need to use stdio's buffering, so using raw `read()` and `write()` calls (or your OS's equivalent) might be slightly faster

Comment: @bdonlan: Agreed, but it's less portable, and the difference is a split-hair.

Comment: @ninjalj: yes, I found this out while testing my answer. It's good to see someone else found the same sweet-spot.

Comment: Just a side remark, you probably should not allocate the buffer on the stack. Mind the name of this site: stackoverflow.

Comment: 4096 is probably a better choice if you expect to be dealing with small files.

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient method will depend greatly on the operating system. For example, in Linux, you can use [`sendfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile):

```
struct stat buf;
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
fstat(fd, &buf);
sendfile(0, fd, NULL, buf.st_size);
```

This does the copy directly in the kernel, minimizing unnecessary memory-to-memory copies. Other platforms may have similar approaches, such as `write()`ing to stdout from a `mmap`ed buffer.

Comment: sendfile() is only for sockets, AFAIK. Maybe you meant mmap(), vmsplice(), splice()?

Comment: `sendfile` can be used for other file descriptors, I believe. splice and friends only work with either to or from a fifo.

Comment: @bdonlan, about splice(), yes, they only work with pipes, that's why you first vmsplice() into a pipe, and then splice() from the pipe.

Comment: Or you can just sendfile :) splice is great when you need to move data from something that's not an ordinary file - that's the limitation of sendfile, it only works on mmappable sources.

Comment: About sendfile(), either the manpage in man-3.25 is outdated, or it only supports sendfile()ing to sockets.

Comment: Ah, indeed. So you'd need to use splice.

Comment: Modern kernel: "In Linux kernels before 2.6.33, out_fd must refer to a socket.  Since Linux 2.6.33 it can be any file.  If it is a regular file, then sendfile() changes the file  offset  appropriately." SO yes, you can use sendfile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `FILE` returned by `fopen` is tipically (always?) buffered, so you first example is not so inefficient as you may think.

The second might perform a little better... if you correct the errors: remember to allocate the buffer, and remember that [puts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/puts/) add a newline!.

Other option is to use binary reads (fread).

Comment: On a cold system, the first sentence is correct. However, While testing with a hot cache, I found per-character to be roughly 200 times slower than using the optimal buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with the data.

this will crash though:

```
char *s;
fgets(s, 600, a);
puts(s);
```

since s is no buffer, just a pointer somewhere.

One way is to read in the whole file into a buffer and work with that
by using fread()

```
filebuffer = malloc(filelength);
fread( buffer, 1, filelength, fp );
```

Answer (score 0):

**What you're doing is plenty good enough** in 99% of applications.  Granted, in most C libraries, `stdio` performs badly, and you'd be better off with [Phong Vo's `sfio` library](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/ref/sfio/sfio.html).  **If you have measurements** showing this is a bottleneck, the natural next step is to allocate a buffer and use `fread`/`fwrite`.  You *don't* want `fgets` because you don't care about newlines.

---

First make it run, then make it right.  You probably don't have to make it fast.